# Cannot export private key from System.keychain with Keychain Access or command line

Tags: macos, security, keychain

I'm trying to export a private key from System.keychain in Keychain Access. I've tried running Keychain Access as a root. No matter what, I always get the following error.

[image]

When I try to export the private key via the command line I get the following.

`security: SecKeychainItemExport: The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, your key was imported with `-x` option for `security import`:

> ```
> <...>
> -x      Specify that private keys are non-extractable after being imported.
> <...>
> ```

When you try to export a key, Security Framework checks whether this attribute is set and refuses to export the key.

Of course, the key is still there and you might be able to find a way to extract it (see [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64323/export-non-extractable-private-key-from-keychain-on-os-x)).

Comment: Thank you! This is five years too late, but at the time, I took a look at the question you shared. I was able to resolve the problem by installing an OS X 10.5 virtual machine and using Keychain Access to export the private key. This works because 10.5 doesn't have any knowledge of that attribute.